# How to go back to node version 5 from node version 6?

Tags: 15.10, nodejs, npm

When I use `whereis node` it returns the paths `node: /usr/local/bin/node /opt/node/bin/node`

```
$ node -v
v6.2.2
```

How should I install node v5.11.1 in Ubuntu 15.10?

Answer (score 2):

you can use [n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) module to help you achieve change,upgrade and remove node versions.
Start by installing the [n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) package

```
$ sudo npm install -g n
```

after that you can install many version of node as you like and activate only one of the using the cmd :

```
$ n  v5.11.1
```

this will either activate the v5.11.1 version if you already install it , or if it doesn't find it it will install and activate it to be the current version that you will work with

Answer (score 0):

You can use Nvm to change back to the older Node version. Nvm is a node version manager that allows you to easily switch the Node version. You can install new versions to try and easily rollback if you want

You can install Nvm easily with a curl and bash one-liner as described in the documentation. It's also available on Homebrew.

To list all the installed versions, run `nvm ls`.

To change the version, run `use 5.11.1`

To set the system-wide default node version, run `nvm alias default 5.11.1`